# Adding to a file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Tags: android, eclipse, udev

I am a complete n00bie, so please be gentle....

I have just started using Eclipse with the Android ADT setup and I attempting to set up a device for development. I have created the following file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

The question is how do I add the device configuration information to the file via the command line as editing the file direct using gedit is not allowed due to permission issues.

Any help or advice very very welcome.

Many thanks in advance.

CT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if gedit is your editor of choice, from the command line write `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and add in the lines you want. There are plenty of examples but the main thing that will be individual to you is the vendor and product id found through a `lsusb` and looking at your device.